# Slider is not working properly in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I develop one website in WordPress.I use the plugin go portfolio plugin through I added the images but the slider is not working properly.so how to make the slider is working properly.I want to make the carousel slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not offer any code to analyse, so how do you think we can help you?

Do you have any errors in the console or something to start with?

If you cannot offer anything, I think you should have the plugin authors have a look at your backend, they often help you out, especially when you are using a paid version:
https://codecanyon.net/item/go-portfolio-wordpress-responsive-portfolio/5741904/support